# MongoDB start issue

Tags: mongodb

```
kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /
$ cd /C/MongoDB/bin

kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /C/MongoDB/bin
$ mongod
bash: mongod: command not found

kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /C/MongoDB/bin
$ ls
bsondump.exe*  mongodump.exe*    mongoperf.exe*     mongotop.exe*
libeay32.dll*  mongoexport.exe*  mongorestore.exe*  ssleay32.dll*
mongo.exe*     mongofiles.exe*   mongos.exe*
mongod.exe*    mongoimport.exe*  mongos.pdb
mongod.pdb     mongooplog.exe*   mongostat.exe*

kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /C/MongoDB/bin
$ mongod
bash: mongod: command not found
```

I try to start the mongodb but I always got command not found error, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: How did you install mongodb? Did you follow https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/ ?

Comment: I have go over the manual again, I downloaded Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ and my system is win8.1 pro x64. did i download it wrong?

Comment: Version should be fine.. Are you starting it in the Command Prompt?  Your terminal looks like an emulated bash shell, that feels wrong on Windows

Comment: I solve it by adding ./mongod

Answer (score 0):

Try  :

> mongod.exe   for start server
>
> mongo.exe for client connection

Comment: Maybe try mongodb.exe*